# Create custom theme in Avalon Dock

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I'm looking to create or edit a theme in AvalonDock 2.0 to my liking, however, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to go about doing this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a custom AvalonDock theme. You can find it in the history of my application.
I abandoned it since we now have a dark theme with which I am fine (see current version).

Have a look at my project at: https://edi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/603e7c6580ad274ea8d306c91cee3125ccde717e

Be sure to download this changeset since the custom theme ExpressionDark is not available in the current version. Creating it was not difficult. I simply used an existing themes project as template and changed the usual suspects like namespace, theme name in ExpressionDarkTheme.cs.

Using the project in this state requires that you compile the AvalonDock sample app in
\02_Libs\AvalonDock

and copy the binaries into:

02_Libs\00_bin\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock

This should enable you to compile the Edi.sln solution and verify the ExpressionDark theme.

Please let me know if you have further questions on this.

Comment: Something that really bothers me is the fact that all examples from Avalon are from earlier versions, and some of the objects changed from  1.x version to 2.0. I saw your code and it's pretty clean (+1)

Comment: Thanks I took an extra effort with StyleCop to get a consistent and clean picture.